# How to change speech rate during speaking using AVSpeechSynthesizer in iOS 7

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

I'd like to change speech rate during speaking text to know how fast.

I tested as below 2 ways , but speech rate does not changed.

```
- (void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString:NSRange)characterRange utterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance{

    // 1. AVSpeechUtterance *SpeechUtterence; 
    SpeechUtterence.rate = fSpeechSpeed;

   // 2. set fSpeechSpeed from other view 
    utterance.rate = fSpeechSpeed;

}
```

Comment: what is the value of `fSpeechSpeed`?

Comment: fSpeechSpeed variable is set from other view.

Comment: Yes, but what is it's value? I mean, is it 0.5? 1? 42? `AVSpeechUtterance`'s `rate`  has a limited range of valid values.

Comment: yes, it's range is 0.0f ~ 1.0f

Answer (score 4):

If the speech synthesizer is already speaking that means you already called the speakUtterance method. At that point changing any of the AVSpeechUtterance instance properties such as rate will not have any effect. If you want to change the rate of the currently speaking utterance you need to use the method you listed above (willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString) to pinpoint your location in the string assigned to the utterance, call the speech synthesizer method stopSpeakingAtBoundary to stop the current utterance, create a new utterance based off of the remaining string and then call speakUtterance again.